# Change the image size on hover without changing the parent div's size

Tags: css

I have a question. I need to change the image size on hover without changing the parent div's size. Also, I have some

tags inside the same div with the image. When I add hover on image and give some pxs to width and height, the

tags move with the image.

```css
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

img:hover {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div class="product-items">
                    <div class="desc">
                        <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/v97OD-MBgNjw8p5crApucVs9RB8=/0x0:2050x1367/1800x1800/filters:focal(1025x684:1026x685)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22022572/bfarsace_201106_4269_012.0.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="cost">
                            <p class="your_product">Ваш товар</p>
                            <p>$89.00</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by using the `transform` property

```css
.product-items{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.img-div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
div:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-items">
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="img-div">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/v97OD-MBgNjw8p5crApucVs9RB8=/0x0:2050x1367/1800x1800/filters:focal(1025x684:1026x685)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22022572/bfarsace_201106_4269_012.0.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="cost">
          <p class="your_product">Ваш товар</p>
          <p>$89.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter your HTML - just scale the img on hover rather than alter its width and height. Scaling will not affect the positioning of other elements as the scaled element keeps its original size as far as they are concerned.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img:hover {
  /*width: 250px;
    height: 250px;*/
  transform: scale(1.25);/* added */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-items">
  <div class="desc">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/v97OD-MBgNjw8p5crApucVs9RB8=/0x0:2050x1367/1800x1800/filters:focal(1025x684:1026x685)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22022572/bfarsace_201106_4269_012.0.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="cost">
      <p class="your_product">Ваш товар</p>
      <p>$89.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add container on image and set `position:relative` and for img `position:absolute`

```css
.img-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
img:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-items">
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/v97OD-MBgNjw8p5crApucVs9RB8=/0x0:2050x1367/1800x1800/filters:focal(1025x684:1026x685)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22022572/bfarsace_201106_4269_012.0.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="cost">
      <p class="your_product">Ваш товар</p>
      <p>$89.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```